# WPF application login window not on top

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm using Prism's MefBootstrapper to initialize my WPF application, as part of this process the Shell window is being initialized.

After Running the MefBootstrapper's Run() method, I'm displaying a login window which connects to a server and in case of a successful connection, the Shell is loaded (from main UI thread).

This login window is running on a new dedicated UI thread, in order not to freeze the progress-bar in this process (connection to the server and especially the Shell loading).

Unfortunately, the login window is not showed on the top and not Focused (even when I'm using:    Activate(), TopMost=true, Focus() ).

```
            //UI mode - a new UI thread is initialized 
            var uiThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var loginWindow = new LoginWindow();

                loginWindow.Show();
                loginWindow.Activate();
                loginWindow.Topmost = true;  
                loginWindow.Topmost = false; 
                loginWindow.Focus();        

                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            });
            uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            uiThread.IsBackground = true;
            uiThread.Start();
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You are probably setting the TopMost flag after the window has already been initialized. Show the relevant parts of the code in your question.

Comment: If the TopMost is set to true before the window is shown, the window has no focus.

Comment: Then should your question not be: How to set Focus on a topmost window? You are just confusing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `uiThread.IsBackground = false;`

Can you send new instance of `LoginWindow` to the thread?

```
        uiThread.Start(new LoginWindow());
```

and then use the loginWindow parameter in the Thread delegate to `Show`.

I guess that would cause the window to render in the current dispatcher context and would render it on the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the *loginWindow* before the *ShellWindow* is created, just before the end of *ConfigureContainer()*.

That way you won't unnecessarily create views - viewmodels in your regions.

Note, it is important that you don't Close the window before you have shown your *ShellWindow* (i.e. hide it on successful login) or else the Application will close too.